# What does "analytica" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

What kind of word form is "analytica"? It sounds English enough, but does it mean anything?

Googling doesn't really doesn't turn up anything helpful.

Comment: It's not in the lexicon as far as I can determine, any more than somnifica,  logica, ethica, publica or biochemica. These Latin words may be appropriated as proper names, but that doesn't automatically confer lexical status on them.  Though the candidate 'formica' seems to have made it now (via genericisation).

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytica simply means analytics. It is not precise English *per se,* but can be used in sentences. the "ica" ending is very common in Greek for instance and perhaps in Latin too. "Ica" has just transformed into "ics" in common English. For instance *mathematica* just means mathematics. In many languages including Greek, Armenian and Russian the correct word for mathematics is mathematica, for analytics is (Analitika) and so on and so forth. Another example is Physica instead of physics.

**EDIT**:

After some research the "ica" is the plural suffix in Latin and "icum" is the singular suffix. The singular of *data* for instance would be *datum.* "ica" basically signifies things that belong to the same collection the same way "ics" does in modern English. Basically this is old Latin way of writing which has evolved into what we know now.

I'd venture forth and say Cambridge Analytica is called "Analytica" and not analytics, because analytica has a more "sciency" cool sound to it.

Comment: @Mehrdad you're welcome. 

WhoEverDownvotes
If you downvote please leave a comment describing what was wrong with the answer.

Comment: Certainly. Assuming you're correct and OED say doesn't list 'analytica', 'It is not precise English per se' should be 'It is not in the lexicon, and therefore off-topic on a site devoted to accepted English usage.  ... Its use in say _Cambridge Analytica_ is a nonce use of Latin, as with say _Ulula_ for the Manchester Grammar School Magazine.'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The OED indeed doesn't list 'analytica'. However words like analytica, physica and mathematica are used in common English. Just about as often as other Latin words that are listed in OED like 'modicum'. I was leaning more towards that.